# call OSGi service through a server thread

Tags: java, sockets, osgi

I have done a client server model using sockets in OSGi. I have a bundle on the server side where my activator class calls a thread which creates a socket and gets the String data from the client side. Now I want to call a service from server side so that I can send this string for some processing. How do I go about this?

This is my Activator class on the server side

```
int serverport=5000;
    Thread t;
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = bundleContext;
        t = new StdServer(serverport,this);
        t.start();
```

The StdServer class extends a thread that handles the socket creation. I want to call a service in the start function of the activator. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at remote services http://r-osgi.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can get service reference with `getService()` and put as a contructor parameter of a new thread.

Comment: Thanks Areo. I sent a Activator object to the thread's constructor and through that, I could get the service reference and the service object.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you right then you are still in the OSGi environment on the server side and what to use a service that is running in the same container (like Karaf).  With your activator you could get it with the context, have you tried that?

Another approach using Bnd Annotations would require declarative services be installed in your container as well.  Then using Bnd Annotations you could annotate a class something like this where the '@Reference' will get the service you need from the container:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Activate;
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Component;
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Deactivate;
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Reference;

//Doesn't have to be called Activator
@Component
public class Activator {
    private BundleContext context;
    private TheServiceINeed theServiceINeed;

 @Activate
 public void Activate(BundleContext context, Map<String, Object> props) {
 this.context = context;

 }

@Deactivate
public void Deactivate() {
    this.context = null;
}

public TheServiceINeed getTheServiceINeed() {
    return theServiceINeed;
}

    //The Service to process my String
@Reference
public void setTheServiceINeed(TheServiceINeed theServiceINeed) {
    this.theServiceINeed = theServiceINeed;
    }

}
```

Are you using [BndTools](http://bndtools.org/) to do your work with? Pretty handy for OSGi Development if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Mr Tony. I used the getContext function to get the context and obtained the service reference object through that.